# How to reload data after filtr or after search in Laravel Filament?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I have column

```
Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('Hesablama')
->getStateUsing(function(Expense $record) {
$totalAmount = $record->getTotalAmount();
return $totalAmount;
})
```

What can I do to reload the data when this value changes when I search or filter?

I came across an Ajax solution. But I don't know where to apply it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: is this what you [want](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/advanced#reloading-the-form-when-a-field-is-updated)?

Comment: I need when the table filtered , The result obtained from there also changes the table, but I want to reload the data after the filter. Because I have a column from which I get Sum() . it doesn't update when you filter it shows the Sum() response of the general table

Comment: @TheBabayeff Did you find a solution? I am running into the same issue